# On Windows 7, is it possible to configure an additional static IPv6 address in addition to a dynamic IPv6 address?

Tags: windows-7, ipv6

I have a Windows 7 box that already has a dynamic address assigned by a router but I would like to add a static address (private/Unique Local - not a link local). I don't see anyway of doing this via the UI unless I turn off dynamic address assignment. Is it possible via the CLI?

EDIT: And how do I make it permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link-local address will always be assigned automatically, regardless of whether you do or don't configure another IPv6 address. The GUI is misleading there. If you configure a static address and then check the adapter configuration (e.g. with `ipconfig /all` or `netsh int ipv6 show address`) you'll see that the adapter now has two IPv6 addresses. And of course you can also assign an IPv6 address via the CLI:

```
netsh int ipv6 add address "INTERFACE" fd72:292b:219f:3038::1
```

Comment: I wasn't interested in a link-local address (link local addresses don't work as easily as global scope address since the interface has to be specified). Running the above CLI command did create a permanent IPv6 address but I could have done the same thing in the GUI by choosing manually assign an address. The important part to me is that the system still gets a router assigned global scope IPv6 address in addition to the static IPv6 address.